# Is it possible to do recursion in Angular without using ng-include?

Tags: angularjs, recursion

Because having a lot of ng-includes dramatically slows down a page, I'm trying to explore the possibility of doing recursion without using ng-includes (I need recursion to created nested tress in the UI layer) or even creating nested trees without using recursion.

I guess it's possible to calculate the number of levels of nesting needed in the controller and do an ng-repeat in the UI layer.

1) Has anyone tried this?
2) Any other ways to do this?

Comment: any prototype or minimal viable demo there already?

Comment: no but it's a general question.  i dont think demo is required.

every example of recursion in angular i've seen is by using ng-include.  there has to be another way to do it without ng-include or not use recursion at all.